# Which are the best web free hosts to practice Django deployment?

Tags: django, deployment, host

I'm a beginner with Django but I'd like to see my projects online without having to pay for the host as it is just to learn to deployment process.

Comment: Why dont you simulate deployment locally, a host is just a computer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), because this question is not a good fit for SO. By the way, you could try [AppFog](https://www.appfog.com/) or [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/).

Answer (score 11):

try [pythonanywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com). imo, its one of the best free django cloud host you can find

Comment: Wow, this is so much nicer than Heroku.

Comment: But isnt it for 3 months? Ofcourse ik its free but still..

Answer (score 6):

[Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) is free. It uses deployment via `git`, so you will also learn that in the process.

I suggest setting up an account at [Github](http://www.github.com) - also free for public repositories - and following the tutorial to setup the repository for your app. Then learn how to deploy that repo to Heroku.

The documentation of both sites is fantastic.